# How to generate unique key in mongoose on node js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, unique

The flow is:

1. I generate `currentKey` (key consist from 3 words separated by `-`)
2. I check if any document in my collection already have `currentKey`.
3. If it is not - `currentKey` will be pasted into my specific document in my collection.
4. But if it is - `currentKey` will be regenerated and all over again.

And the problem is mongoose have asynchronous callback that will run when query will finish executing. And i don't know how to implement my flow with this asynchronously flow. As the example (this is just example for convenience, it's not a existing framework or etc.) what i did on php is like next:

```
$currentKey = someService.GenerateKey();
//exists() returns true or false
while($db->find('tablename', ['key' => $currentKey])->exists())
{
    $currentKey = someService.GenerateKey();
}
//It's update 'tablename' where `id` equals to $someUserId and set `key` to $currentKey value
$db->update('tablename', ['id' => $someUserId], ['key' => $currentKey]);
```

Can you help me, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Promises are designed for that.

```
function generateUniqueKey(modelId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    currentKey = someService.GenerateKey();
    MyModel.count({ key: currentKey })
      .then(count => {
        if (count > 0) {
          generateUniqueKey(modelId);
        } else {
          MyModel.update({ id: modelId }, { $set: { key: currentKey } })
            .then(resolve(currentKey));
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

generateUniqueKey(someUserId).then(key => console.log('Generated unique key:', key));
```

But if you don't care about the result you can just remove the `Promise` mechanism and let the `generateUniqueKey()` method end on its own.

```
function generateUniqueKey(modelId) {
  currentKey = someService.GenerateKey();
  MyModel.count({ key: currentKey })
    .then(count => {
      if (count > 0) {
        generateUniqueKey(modelId);
      } else {
        MyModel.update({ id: modelId }, { $set: { key: currentKey } })
          .then(() => console.log('Generated unique key:', currentKey))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

generateUniqueKey(someUserId);
```